# Google App Engine 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

We are randomly getting the following error when using Google App Engine standard environment python2.7:

> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

An example stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1535, in **call**
> rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1529, in **call**
> rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1278, in default_dispatcher
> return route.handler_adapter(request, response)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 1102, in **call**
> return handler.dispatch()   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 572, in dispatch
> return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
> line 570, in dispatch
> return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~boutirapp/prod20210407-0912.434271348867830388/api/sixdegree.py",
> line 172, in post
> body = self.process(*args, **kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~boutirapp/prod20210407-0912.434271348867830388/pages/paydollar_datafeed.py",
> line 89, in process
> BTOrder.confirmOrder(Ref, user)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~boutirapp/prod20210407-0912.434271348867830388/entities/btorder.py",
> line 2034, in confirmOrder
> self = db.run_in_transaction_options(xg_on_retry_5, cls._confirmOrderTransaction, orderId, paypalTxId, paypalResp)   File
> "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py",
> line 2641, in RunInTransactionOptions
> function, *args, **kwargs)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py",
> line 2716, in _RunInTransactionInternal
> ok, result = _DoOneTry(function, args, kwargs)   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/fdc6d631da52d25b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py",
> line 2770, in _DoOneTry
> if _GetConnection().commit(): AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

The error occurs randomly when we are committing a datastore transaction using the `google.appengine.ext.db` library. The same lines of code might work fine when we retry immediately after the error. It also doesn't look like an error of our code as it is a missing attribute from a library object.

Any help to tackle the error is appreciated.

Edit: the error started to occur on 8 March 2021. We didn't change any related code close to that day.

Comment: ```google.appengine.ext.db``` was superseeded by ```google.appengine.ext.ndb``` long ago. Sometimes (this has been my experience), advancement in other areas/technologies results in some side effects in older technologies especially when there is no specific effort to maintain backward compatibility. If it won't cost you much effort, I would suggest switching to ```google.appengine.ext.ndb```. I have never encountered your error while using ```google.appengine.ext.ndb```

Comment: Yes, we also use `google.appengine.ext.ndb` in some other areas of the same project and haven't encountered the issue there. However, the legacy part that uses `google.appengine.ext.db` is quite huge and we might not have the resources to immediately migrate it all. Therefore, any workarounds for this issue is still appreciated. Or if this can be confirmed to be a `google.appengine.ext.db` issue that won't be fixed, we might be able to prioritize the migration more easily

Comment: Ok. I understand. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution. I was just going off my past experience where I encounter certain intermittent bugs and when I upgrade to the latest or newer version, it goes away.

Comment: It looks like this could be because `google.appengine.ext.db` is deprecated. In this [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184874603) they are still discussing about it.

Comment: Yes, we cross-posted in the issue tracker. The error is still happening to us every day. It is quite weird that no one else is seemingly facing the same issue. We can't be the only one running legacy code, can we?